# What does it mean when a Python script uses 22% of the memory but 100% of the CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu-usage

I'm running a computationally intensive Python script in a virtual box. Spyder shows it only uses 22% of the memory that is available to the VB, but it does use 100% of the CPU. How can this be and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Because it's *computationally intensive*, and the CPU is being used to do those computations. There's no correlation between CPU and memory use; you can have code that uses the CPU extensively and little memory, and code that uses lots of memory but little CPU.

Comment: What exactly seems strange to you, and what do you think needs to be fixed? A car's engine can reach maximum RPM regardless of whether it's carrying full cargo load or just the driver's mass.

Comment: Are you parallel processing? Are you asking it to do a whole bunch of small tasks or 1 computational expensive one? It is hard to help without any information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not parallel processing. I'm solving a PDE for a large number of timesteps, one after the other. I'll be glad to provide any other information. Interesting, I didn't know there is no correlation between CPU and memory use. Which tasks are usually intensive on CPU, which on memory?

Comment: for example `while(true);` would use lots of cpu cycles and no memory...